# Mapbox's LocationLayerPlugin not updating location when Proguard is enabled

Tags: android, mapbox, mapbox-android

I'm using Mapbox's LocationLayerPlugin v0.6.0 with Proguard enabled.

In release builds, the location layer isn't requesting location updates: no GPS usage icon when in foreground, and the location becomes stale a few seconds after the first launch and never updates. I'm building the plugin without providing a LocationEngine, using `public LocationLayerPlugin(MapView mapView, MapboxMap mapboxMap)`.

It doesn't happen in debug builds (no Proguard) or if I explicitly disable Proguard in the release build (`minifyEnabled=false`). The `proguard-rules.pro` file doesn't have any specific rules for Mapbox (both SDK and plugin), I've tried adding the ones from https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/app/proguard-rules.pro but the issue remains.

Are there other rules to be added? I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using google play location services, and the `GoogleLocationEngine`, you can try adding

```
-keep class com.google.android.gms.** { *; }
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.**
```

to your `proguard-rules.pro` file.

I was able to reproduce the issue and above setup helped.

However, if you are only using the `AndroidLocationEngine` there has been some issues with that engine recently, you can follow the [issue tracker](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-events-android) for more info.

For more context, if you will not manually add the google play location services dependency to your project, the `LocationEngineProvider#obtainBestLocationEngineAvailable` used by the [default constructor](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-plugins-android/blob/master/plugin-locationlayer/src/main/java/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/plugins/locationlayer/LocationLayerPlugin.java#L700) will return the `AndroidLocationEngine`, otherwise, it will return the `GoogleLocationEngine`.

Comment: The rules you gave did the trick. The ones in the file I linked are similar but only keep public classes and methods, I guess it wasn't enough. Thanks